# request mysql with rank result different for same request

Tags: sql

not the same result of request when it run the first time (cli sqlplus)
first result 104 the @rank < 6 is not taken

then when I re-execute (2 or 3 or 4 time) the same request 
    second result 83 the @rank < 6 is  taken

the same request :

```
select count(*) 
from (
    (select a.rank,a.g 
     from (
       SELECT t.* 
       FROM (
         select  @rank:= CASE WHEN @group = nom_toto THEN @rank +1 ELSE 1 END rank,
                 @group:= table.nom_toto g 
        from table  
        where sonde = 0
     ) t 
     WHERE t.rank <=6
  ) a 
     left JOIN (
       select table.nom_toto 
       from service_list 
         join ...)
  ) f 
  group by f.nom_toto, f.rank,f.g;
```

why the first time the rank is not taken?

Comment: That isn't Oracle syntax...?

Comment: I removed the `oracle` as that query clearly is not for Oracle

Comment: sorry it is not oracle but mysql